# Rewrite condition in .htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, pattern-matching, conditional-statements

I have been trying to get a rewrite condition to work, but it's just not having it (it is not redirecting at all so I believe it is not matching the condition). This is an example of a dynamic URL I am trying to redirect:

http://mysite.com/cgi-bin/sh000001.pl?REFPAGE=FT10

to:

http://mysite.com/siteref/FT10/

and this is the script:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^REFPAGE=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^cgi-bin/sh000001.pl$ siteref/%1/ [L,R=301]
```

(I do have RewriteEngine On)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the RewriteCond is working, but the problem may be that you've got /cgi-bin/ scriptaliased and it's possible that mod_alias is resolving the request before it gets to mod_rewrite. You can try removing your `ScriptAlias` of /cgi-bin/.